# How to bind text from textboxes to SQL Server table with IDENTITY (1, 1 )

Tags: c#, sql-server

Just like in title (C#, Visual Studio 2015).

I have a `Database.mdf` file in Visual Studio. I have 5 texboxes and I want to bind the text from this texboxes to database tables.

My primary key has an `IDENTITY(1,1)` attribute. I don't know how I can resolve this problem. Binding should be pressing by the button click.

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Mariusz\Desktop\SerwisKomputerowyDB\SerwisKomputerowyDB\SerwisKomputerowyDB\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True");
 conn.Open();

 SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
 newCmd.Connection = conn;
 newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 newCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni] VALUES (,'" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "')";

 newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 conn.Close();
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You will get better responses to questions if you can narrow it down to some specific lines of code and to explicitly ask a question about one particular thing. As explained in the guides, [don't just copy in your entire program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: please tell what the error are you getting

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table with an `IDENTITY` column, you need to make sure **NOT** to insert a value into that column when you insert data.

So you need to **explicitly define** the column names you insert into - which is really always a good idea and you should do this always, anyway:

```
// define query WITH PARAMETERS! Don't concatenate together your SQL - never EVER !
string insertQry = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni] (TextCol1, TextCol2, TextCol3, TextCol4, TextCol5) " + 
                   "VALUES (@TextValue1, @TextValue2, @TextValue3, @TextValue4, @TextValue5);";

// create connection and command object                   
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Mariusz\Desktop\SerwisKomputerowyDB\SerwisKomputerowyDB\SerwisKomputerowyDB\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQry, conn))
{
    // set up parameters and define values
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextValue1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextValue2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextValue3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox3.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextValue4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox4.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextValue5", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox5.Text;

    // open connection, execute INSERT command, close connection  
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the insert statement with column names
e.g.

`INSERT INTO [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni](column2, column3) VALUES (value2, value3)";`

Refer [w3school article - SQL INSERT INTO Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

To prevent sql injection vulnerability [check this Reference](http://www.bobby-tables.com)  i.e. by concatenating values, use parameterized queries.
e.g.

```
newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
newCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni](column2, column3) VALUES (@val1, @val2)";
newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", textBox1.Text);
newCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", textBox2.Text);
newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string insertQry = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[KlienciIndywidualni] (Imię, Nazwisko, Telefon, E-mail,Adres) " +
                           "VALUES (@Imię, @Nazwisko, @Telefon, @E-mail, @Adres);";


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mariusz\Desktop\AplikacjaNaInzynierie\AplikacjaNaInzynierie\Baza.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQry, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Imię", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nazwisko", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telefon", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@E-mail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Adres", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox5.Text;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

I still have error...

Comment: +  e {X = 33 Y = 8 Button = Left} System.EventArgs {System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs}

Comment: ***WHAT ERROR?!?!?*** You keep teasing us about that error - but seriously - we **CANNOT** read your screen, nor your mind - you will **HAVE TO TELL US!**

Comment: Program crush at line: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();